# JavaScript new keyword and objects scopes

Tags: jquery, function, object, new-operator

Later today, I was scrolling through ejhon.com slides and I found out the following:

Give this code

```
function katana () {
this.myvar = true;
}
katana ();
console.info (myvar);
```

Past the moment I compiled the code, I thought that myvar is attached to the katana function. Actually, it gets attached to the window objects, which pollutes the global namespace.

I returned to my projects, which all uses the same approach.. a little bit differently

```
function katana () {
this.myvar = true;
}
var xyz = new katana();
console.info (myvar);
```

I have a function object and instead of executing the function, I just create a new instance of it (I'm not actually quite sure what's happening). I then use xyz to store values and use those values through prototyped methods to do some jobs.

What surprised me is when I did some debugging with FireBug is that xyz is not existent. There is no variables attached to window object. Why?

I did some more debugging and the xyz object is attached to window > object, but in the DOM it's not apparent and has no traces. There is also something new in the debugging window, a node called 'scopechain' with a call and that has the values of the xyz object.

Okay, what's happening underneath? Is that a good method that I should stick with or shall I look for an alternative?
I have looked at some questions and answers, I'm mainly looking for what this method do in the background.

Comment: read this http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Comment: Actually I was scrolling through it. I'm just looking for a deeper explanation as those slides only show results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `new katana()`, Javascript calls the `katana` function, with a new blank object as `this`.  Once it returns, presumably initialized, the new object (or whatever `katana` returns, as long as it's an object) is set up so that its 'prototype' (the object that it'll inherit fields and such from) is the same as the `katana` function's prototype.

Yeah, that didn't make much sense either the first time i went through it.  The oversimplified version is, you say `new katana()`, and Javascript creates what'll be a `katana` instance and lets the `katana` function initialize it.  You say `katana()`, and `this` is basically the last object in the call stack to have been used in an instance method call.  (If your caller was `x.foo`, `this == x`.)  If there's no such object, seems `this` is the same as `window`.

As for why `xyz` isn't showing up, you declared the variable with `var`.  That changes the scope.  If you got rid of that, you'd see a `window.xyz`.

Comment: Good answer. I'm mainly looking to know what's happening beneath the ground. What about the new 'scopechain' node in FireBug. Also xyz seems to be attached to the window object, it's just not present in the DOM.

Comment: I don't use FireBug (or Firefox, for that matter).  The 'scopechain' stuff may be Firefox's way of keeping track of scope.  It doesn't seem to be there in Chrome, though, and it's not a standard Javascript/ECMAScript thing as far as i know.