# JS function to return function, shares data which should be private

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a function which returns another function. I want separate information when each of the inner function is run, but this isn't happening. I know that explanation is not great, so I've put together a small example.

```
            var testFn = function(testVal) {
                return (function(testVal) {
                    var test = testVal;

                    this.getVal = function() {
                        return test;
                    }

                    return that;

                })(testVal);
            }
            var a = testFn(4);
            var b = testFn(2);
            console.log(b.getVal(), a.getVal());
```

This outputs 2, 2. What I would like is 2, 4 to be output. I know this isn't explained perfectly, so if it's not clear what I'm trying to achieve, can someone explain why the variable seems to be shared across the two functions?

Thanks

Comment: ha, for calling this that!

Comment: Haha, that's because I cut the example down from my actual code

Comment: lol ok, made me laugh out loud at work

Comment: @JamieHutber Got any good explanations of the actual question though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

```
var testFn = function(testVal) {
  var test = testVal
  return {
    getVal: function() {
      return  test
    }
  }   
};

var ab = testFn (4)
var ac = testFn (2)

console.log(ab.getVal(),ac.getVal()) //4 //2
```

The problem in your code is `this.getVal()` / returning `this`

because 'this' refers to the global scope / `Window`

You are glubbering with the global namespace and overwriting `Window.getVal()` , the moment you are setting `b = testFn (2)`
This results in overwriting `a`s method `getVal` too because they both refer to the global Object and always share the same method `getVal`

Therefore they share the same closure and are outputing 2

`console.log("The same: " + (Window.a === Window.b)) // true`
`console.log("The same: " + (a === b)) // true`

you can see that if you change it a little:

```
        var testFn = function(testVal) {
          var x = {}
            return (function(testVal) {
                var test = testVal;
                x.getVal = function () {
                  return test;
                }
                 return x

            })(testVal);
        }
        var a = testFn(4);
        var b = testFn(2);
        console.log(b.getVal(), a.getVal());//4 2
```

it suddenly works because it results in 2 different Objects returned (btw you don't even need the outer closure)
`console.log("The same: " + (a === b)) // false`

Here are the JSbins [First](http://jsbin.com/eyaqak/1/edit) / [Second](http://jsbin.com/ekutaj/1/edit)

I hope you understand this, I'm not good in explaining things
If theres anything left unclear, post a comment and I'll try to update the answer

Answer (score 2):

This question comes down to the context in which functions are invoked in JavaScript.

A function that is invoked within another function is executed in the context of the global scope.

In your example, where you have this code:

```
var testFn = function(testVal) {
  return (function(testVal) {
    var test = testVal;
    this.getVal = function() {
      return test;
    }
    return this;
  })(testVal);
}
```

The inner function is being called on the *global* scope, so `this` refers to the global object. In JavaScript a function executed within another function is done so with its scope set to the global scope, *not* the scope of the function it exists within. This tends to trip developers up a fair bit (or at least, it does me!).

For argument's sake, lets presume this is in a browser, so hence `this` refers to the `window` object. This is why you get `2` logged twice, because the second time this runs, `this.getVal` overwrites the `getVal` method that was defined when you ran `var a = testFn(4);`.

JavaScript scopes at function level, so every function has its own scope:

```
var x = 3;
function foo() {
  var x = 2;
  console.log(x);
};
console.log(x); //gives us 3
foo(); // logs 2
```

So what you want to do is run that inner function *in the context of the `testFn` function*, not in the global scope. You can run a function with a specific context using the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). I also recorded a [screencast on `call` and `apply`](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/11/screencast-call-and-apply) which discusses this in greater detail. The basic usage of `call` is:

```
function foo() {...}.call(this);
```

That executes `foo` in the context of `this`. So, the first step is to make sure your inner function is called in the right context, the context of the `testFn` method.

```
var testFn = function(testVal) {
  return (function(testVal) {
    var test = testVal;
    this.getVal = function() {
      return test;
    }
    return this;
  }.call(this, testVal);
}
```

The first parameter to `call` is the context, and any arguments following that are passed to the function as parameters. So now the inner function is being called in the right scope, it wont add `getVal` to the global scope, which is a step in the right direction :)

Next though you also need to make sure that every time you call `testFn`, you do so in a new scope, so you're not overwriting `this.getVal` when you call `testFn` for the second time. You can do this using the `new` keyword. [This SO post on the `new` keyword is well worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript). When you do `var foo = new testFn()` you create and execute a new instance of `testFN`, hereby creating a new scope. [This SO question is also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408960/javascript-new-keyword-and-objects-scopes).

All you now need to do is change your declaration of `a` and `b` to:

```
var a = new testFn(4);
var b = new testFn(2);
```

And now `console.log(b.getVal(), a.getVal());` will give `2`, `4` as desired.

I put a [working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/alehun/1/) which should help clear things up. Note how this example defines `this.x` globally and within the function, and see which ones get logged. Have a play with this and hopefully it might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

The output you get is (2,2) because when you do

```
var that = this;
```

what you actually get is the global object (window),
the object that holds all the global methods and variables in your javascript code.
(Note that every variable that is not nested under an object or function is global and
every function that is not nested under an **object** is global, meaning that functions that are nested under a function **are still global**)

so, when you set:

```
var test = testVal;

this.getVal = function() {
    return test;
}
```

you actually set the function "getVal" in the **global** object, and in the next run you will again set the same function - overriding the first.
To achieve the affect you wanted I would suggest creating and object and returning it in the inner function (as @Glutamat suggested before me):

```
var testFn = function(testVal) {
        return new Object({
            getVal: function() {
                return testVal;
            }
        });
}
var a = testFn(4);
var b = testFn(2);
console.log(b.getVal(), a.getVal());
```

In this way, in the outer function we create an object with an inner function called "getVal" that returns the variable passed to the outer function (testVal).
Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/utoviz/1/edit) if you want to play around with it
(thanks to @Glutamat for introducing this site, I never heard of it and it's really cool :D)

Comment: You're welcome =) i discovered it when jsfiddle, was down, and it turned out i like it more, mainly because the inbuilt console and the style.